# Disable button after a click for 2 seconds and resume back

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click a resend button first time, the button will disable for 2 seconds.After 2 seconds the button will enable?
I am using this code

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
            btn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.d(TAG,"resend1");
                }
            },1000);
        }
    });
```

But this code is not working properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this for this purpose you can use Handler(`import android.os.Handler;`)

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setEnabled(false);

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                btn.setEnabled(true);
                Log.d(TAG,"resend1");

        }
    },2000);// set time as per your requirement 
    }
});
```

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: This helped me too...thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timer for this

```
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               myButton.setEnabled(false);

    Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
    buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution

1. In your button click

   ```
    long  mLastClickTime;
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           disableButtonTwoSecs();
         // Here your implementation

       }
   });

   public static boolean disableButtonTwoSecs() {
   if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 2000) {
       return true;
   }
   mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
   return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: if(disableButtonTwoSecs()){
            return@OnClickListener
        }